# How to make DOMDocument::loadXML stop changing/decoding HTML entities

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, domdocument

`DOMDocument::loadXML` changes/decodes HTML entities. 
I have this string:

```
<description>![CDATA[&lt;br &gt; ....
```

After DOMDocument::loadXML I get:

```
<![CDATA[<br > ...
```

It looks like it decodes **HTML entities**, how can it be stopped? I want to get the same output, without decoding it.

Comment: This is normal behaviour: the encoding of entities exists so they can be decoded as text values when required. Remember the text content of a node is a string, not another element thus maintaining the separation between content and markup. Should you serialise the DOM they will be re-encoded.

Comment: Actually, CDATA section content does not get decoded: https://eval.in/551067

Comment: Thank you for your comments

Comment: Please provide the exact code used to reproduce the issue.